# Converting an int to a byte of a certain size in python

Tags: python, bit-manipulation

I'm trying to create an array of bits in python that are two binary numbers into a fixed width.

For eg.

`[11,90]   ----> 0000101101011010`

What I've tried/ Problems I've encountered:

1. `bin(11)` => 0b1010 (which is not the fixed width I need)
2. String manipulation using format `'{0:11b}'.format(8)` (this works but I'd like to avoid converting to strings and back if I can. It seems like a lot of overhead to do essentially a shift and add)

Comment: Python doesn't support bit arrays. Or what do you mean?

Comment: How did you get `0b0000101101011010` from `11` and `90`?

Comment: `bin` returns a string. I wouldn't worry about the overhead unless you actually see it causing problems, it's unlikely to matter much.  If you are worried, then you should build your own `list`s of `True` and `False`, which are as close as you are likely to get to a bit array.  `'{:0>8b}{:0>8b}'.format(x, y)` should be sufficient

Comment: @Galen I see it now.  11 in binary is `1011`, and `00001011` is the first half of the number, 90 is `1011010` and `01011010` is the second half. So it seems as if they want to convert numbers in a list to binary, add 0's to the front until each is 8 bits long, then append them together.

Comment: Guessing from your desired output, you wish the first number to fit (zero filled) in the first set of 8 characters, and the second (also zero filled) on the second octet. Is this correct?

Comment: Try `a = 11 << 8 | 90`, then `bin(a)` produces `0b101101011010`

Comment: @chris Ah. I figured that was what he was after, but Chrome's on-page search was making it look like the last 8 bits were wrong.

Comment: @Galen Yep, same thing happened to me :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`struct`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/struct.html):

```
bin(int.from_bytes(struct.pack('>bb', 11, 90), byteorder='big'))
```

If you want the leading 0s:

```
'{:016b}'.format(int.from_bytes(struct.pack('>bb', 11, 90), byteorder='big'))
```

Answer (score 2):

Guessing what you want to do, since you're not very detailed on your question, you can use `bin(x)[2:]` removing the first two characters, then zero fill it with `str.zfill(length)` and then concatenating your two numbers, like so:

```
print(bin(11)[2:].zfill(8) + bin(90)[2:].zfill(8))
```

Will print: `0000101101011010`